# Cómo evitar que un div se actualize al cargar la página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quiero saber si es posible que al recargar la página se actualize todo menos un div específico

```
<body>
<div id='no-recargable'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: No es posible, si acaso puedes guardar cierta informacion del div con `localStorage` o parecidos, o cosas como shadowDom... pero creo que todo esto depende de cual es el proposito de evitar que recargue el elemento

Comment: El motivo es que tengo unas funciones donde el usuario puede cambiar la letra, color etc...

Comment: Eso puedes resolverlo con [Variables CSS](https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/)... Es decir, lo que hacen las funciones es solo cambiar los valores de las propiedades? Porque si de eso se trata no veo la necesidad de recargar la pagina

Comment: Gracias. el boton de recargar y el f5 si se puede bloquear no?

Comment: Ni se pueden bloquear ni se deben bloquear, no puedes quitar al usuario la posibilidad de recargar. Cómo a comentado @IvanS95 localStorage te puede servir. Simplemente guarda ahí la fuente y el color que elija el usuario y aplicalo cuando se cargue la página, en el onLoad por ejemplo. localStorage persiste entre recargas https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes guardar en el localStorage los datos dentro del div y luego cada vez que lo habrás invocas una funcion que pregunte si tiene algo el localStorage y luego lo insertas dentro del div

```
    var contenido

   (function(){
    //Aqui guardas los datos que quieres que se almacenen
    localStorage.contenido_a_guardar = '<img src="imagen_de_ejamplo.png">'

    //Aqui lo almacenas en una variable si ya existe
    contenido_div = localStorage.contenido_a_guardar';

    //Aqui lo insertas en el Html
    document.getElementById('no-recargable').innerHTML = contenido_div
        )()
```